# Is there a way in an ASP.NET MVC project to create a carousel in the main home page of seeder data URL images?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am currently completing an ASP.NET MVC project. I have three folders in my views - Home, Movie and Reviews. I would like the Home Index cshtml page to display a carousel of the poster urls which comes from a serviceseeder.

```
@foreach (var movie in Model)
{
    <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="data:image/jpg;base64,@Convert.ToBase64String(movie.PosterUrl)" alt="@movie.Title">
    </div>
}
```

However, I keep getting this error,

> Error CS1579: foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'Movie' because 'Movie' does not contain a public instance or extension definition for 'GetEnumerator'

Does anyone have any advice on the steps I should take? I am a beginner.

Comment: What is `Model` in this case? It should be a List or Array...

Comment: apologies... @model Movie ... it is an IList...

Comment: Make it a `List` instead of `Ilist`